# Meaning and origin of the phrase "slips don't count"

Tags: american-english, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, phrase-origin

I ran across this expression recently in some *Popeye* cartoon [EDIT: it was [*Never Sock a Baby*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13E_aWn5mEU&t=5m13s), 1939], but it seems to have been a recognized slang expression with maybe even a bit of old-timey flavor before then.

> "Enoch," said Mr. Stratford, with a smile, "you said too much that time."
>
> "Perhaps I did," said the old farmer, "but **slips don't count**."
>   —[*The Hundredth Man* (Frank Stockton, 1886)](https://books.google.com/books?id=9HYAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA504&dq=%22slips+don%27t+count%22)

Another example:

> Watch my smoke when I get into these Hood Shoes. They don't cramp a fellow's style when he's in action. Let the lads on the other team cry "**Slips don't count!**" Slips don't count against our score for our fellows all wear Hood Shoes. —[Hood Shoes advertisement, 1923](https://books.google.com/books?id=DUBOAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA376&dq=%22slips+don%27t+count%22)

What does the phrase mean, and where/when did it arise?

Comment: It doesn’t seem to be an established expression. Google books yields no results: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slips+don%27t+count&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=

Answer (score 5):

Some Google Books results strongly imply that the phrase originates from the children's game of [marbles](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marbles_(game)).

> [We] played a lot of marbles at Rusk Elementary in Palestine in the Thirties. The games I best remember are Cat Eye, Four Square, and Bullring — "Knucks down!" and "**Slips don't count!**" —[*Texas Toys and Games*, chapter "Marbles"](https://books.google.com/books?id=fkQPsVLhq20C&pg=PA150&dq=%22slips+don%27t+count%22)

And:

> You all know the saying youngsters use in marble games — "**Slips don't count!**" In this case slips did count. —[*The Fraternal Monitor*, 1952–1953](https://books.google.com/books?id=JtLuAAAAMAAJ&q=%22slips+don%27t+count%22&dq=%22slips+don%27t+count%22)

I suppose the original meaning would have been something like "Come on, my thumb slipped! I should be able to re-do that shot." That is, a version of the [mulligan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulligan_(games)) rule. Similar house rules about "slips" might be seen today in billiards or golf.

The two examples in the question seem to be from long after the phrase became a stock phrase, because they're both punning on slightly different meanings of the word "slip" (a slip of the foot, a slip of the tongue) and don't seem to have anything to do with do-overs; they're just punning on the form of the phrase.

As for year-of-origin, I have no idea.